# What parameters are valid to be together to create an HWND?

Tags: model-view-controller, mfc, overlay

I'm trying to create a window using `CWnd::CreateEx()`.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the parameters correct to get it to generate a `HWND` (function always returns `FALSE`).

```
class COverlay : public CWnd
{
public:
    COverlay();

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(COverlay, CWnd)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

COverlay::COverlay()
{
}

class CMyView : CView
{
public:
    CMyView() {}
    int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct);

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyView, CView)
    ON_WM_CREATE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

int CMyView::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CView::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    m_overlay.CreateEx(WS_EX_COMPOSITED | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
        , _T("Static"), _T(""), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, CRect(), this, -1);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to create a click through window that overlays the `CMyView`.  In this way I can paint over the view via the overlay and not get flickering as the OS should handle the double buffering and I will only have to deal with the view implementation in a minimal fashion.  I will also have an `ON_WM_SIZE` hander to deal with resizing the overlay to the extents of the view.

What am I doing wrong?

Is there an easier way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: From [extended window styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx): *"Windows 8: The WS_EX_LAYERED style is supported for top-level windows and child windows. Previous Windows versions support WS_EX_LAYERED only for top-level windows."* Unless you are targeting Windows 8 and above, this is a bug. Also, `WM_EX_TRANSPARENT` doesn't do what you think (*"The window should not be painted until siblings beneath the window have been painted. The window appears transparent because the bits of underlying sibling windows have already been painted."*).

Comment: @IInspectable, ok, so I'll try using a top level window.  Might do some odd things though. As for the `WM_EX_TRANSPARENT` flag, yes, that is exactly what I want it for, so that I can paint images with an alpha channel.

Comment: @IInspectable, I added `WS_EX_TOPMOST` to the extended styles, but it still didn't work.

Comment: You should get a 'last error' trace, is it 0x0000057E, "Cannot create a top-level child window."?

Comment: You are making a child window `CWnd` with `L"Static"` classname, and `WS_CHILD` flag, then adding `WS_EX_TOPMOST` which is for popup window... You should explain your goal instead. Are you trying to make a button with transparent background and some GDI picture on it?

Comment: @lakeweb, using `GetLastError()` I got success (`0`).

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, I'm trying to create a window which I'll draw on (some stuff with an ALPHA channel) but will not intercept any mouse events, allowing the windows below to capture them.  I'm very new to creating windows in this fashion, and only used `L"Static"` as it was already a predefined window class.  I recognize that I will probably have to do something else, but I'm not exactly sure what.  Perhaps I can use a dialog class?

Answer (score 0):

`WS_POPUP` flag is required to create window with transparency level:

```
static CString className = AfxRegisterWndClass(0);
DWORD style = WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_POPUP;
DWORD styleEx = WS_EX_LAYERED;// | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
if (!m_overlay.CreateEx(styleEx, className, 0, style, CRect(), this, 0))
{
    //error...
    return;
}
m_overlay.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(0, 255 * 50 / 100, LWA_ALPHA);
m_overlay.SetWindowPos(0, 0, 0, 400, 300, SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
```

Or to change the transparency color:

```
COLORREF transparentColor = RGB(255, 0, 0);
...
m_overlay.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(transparentColor, 0, LWA_COLORKEY);

void COverlay::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    CRect rc;
    GetClientRect(&rc);
    dc.FillSolidRect(rc, transparentColor);

    //opaque drawings...
    dc.TextOut(0, 0, L"Test...");
}
```

Note, `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` is commented out because that only affects mouse clicks, otherwise it doesn't change the appearance. You can add that flag back in.

This window is popup so it doesn't move when you move the frame window or child window. You would have to override frame and child frame window's `OnWindowPosChanged` to move it manually to sync with View window.